# Sequence of numbers and their sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Peter wrote 555 numbers. First number is 2, second number is 3, a every number, starting from second one, is equal to product and minus one of a number before and number after it. What is the sum of all those numbers?

My attempt: I wrote down the sequence, but I'm looking for a clear formula which would sum them up, if such formula exists.

Comment: What did you get for the sequence? (If you have the right sequence, there is a simple pattern that makes it easy to sum the first $555$ numbers in it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence is $2,3,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,1, \dots$, as you probably observed. Since this will clearly repeat forever and the length of the repeating sequence is $5$, there will be exactly $111$ repetitions of this sequence in the $555$ numbers. So the sum of these numbers is $111 \cdot (2+3+2+1+1) = 111 \cdot 9 = 999$.